# add movie clip on the second frame with as3

Tags: actionscript-3

how can i add a movie clip on a specific frame using addChild called in a class with AS3 ,
my problem is how access to the specific frame

thank you

Comment: I deleted my answer that suggested using `MovieClip.addFrameScript()` because I wasn't sure if that was the correct.

Comment: @Taurayi - Although I didn't see your answer, injecting code onto the second frame might well work, although there may be scope issues

Comment: A little more information is required to answer this accurately.  What is the class that the code will go in, and what is it's relation to the timeline onto which you want to add the movieclip?

Comment: @shaneTheHat I think it was right in terms of doing what the question is asking for, but I can tell that there is more to the question that my answer doesn't cover. Actually I'll undelete it and you can see for yourself.

Comment: @shaneTheHat sorry I deleted it again, after reading it I realized it wasn't correct at all. I wrote "`addFrameScript(0, addChild(new Sprite()));` This will add a `Sprite` object on the first frame." Now I believe it actually adds the `Sprite` object to the parent `MovieClip` object FROM the first frame.

Comment: @Taurayi - don't worry about it.  Without a bit more info on the setup we're only really guessing anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tricky thing about this would be to handle the frame 'live cycle'...

The way I would do it, is:

- Add an event listener for [FRAME_CONSTRUCTED](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#FRAME_CONSTRUCTED)
- Send your movieclip and stop it at your desired frame.
- Attach your symbol on the handler of    the event.

Something like this:

```
mc.addEventListener(Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, _addChild );
mc.gotoAndStop(2);
function _addChild(e:Event):void{
    mc.addChild( new Square) //Library symbol

}
```